# Where to find Sharepoint 2010 javascript api

Tags: javascript

I recently need to do some customization with the Sharepoint's rich text editor. When I looked the [Javascript Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538253%28v=office.14%29.aspx) provided by MSDN, I found it very general also missing some namespace like RTE. I've found some code examples online which use methods like RTE.Cursor.get_range().get_text(). So where did those people find the detail Javascript reference? By reading the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documented API. However you could run the following command in a browser console to print out all available functions.

```
var nspace = "SP";
for(var i in eval(nspace))
{
    console.log(i + " = " + eval(nspace+"."+i));
}
```

This will dump out what is in memory, you can target any namespace you need. Note this works for any javascript library.